# Try to import a database with sql script file

Tags: postgresql

I try to import the small database from this website:

https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgrespro/12/demodb-bookings-installation

in Postgresql. I tried the restore button and choosed the sql file but it fails with the message:

"pg_restore: Error: Input file is apparently a dump in text format. Please use psql".

Then I tried to run the sql command from the file in the sql query, but it fails with the message:

"invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8".

Does anybody know how I can import it? Thx in advance!

Comment: What "restore button" are you referring to?

Comment: I mean if you create a new database and give it a name. Then open the new data base and below Delete/Drop is the "Restore..." function.

Comment: Yes, but are you using any specific tool? Maybe pgadmin? Postgresql does not have any "buttons", its a database server. I suspect you are trying to use pg_restore when in fact you should be using psql. See here, in the section "or with a plain text dump" https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-use-pgdump-and-pgrestore-multi-host-enviorment

Comment: okay thank you, yes I use pgadmin. Now I tried to click the dabase name in pgadmin an choosed PSQL Tool. Then I uses the command: $ pg_restore -h localhost test < /home/postgres/dump.sql

Comment: and I replaced dump.sql for my filename.. but nothing happens :(

Comment: You have to use psql not pg_restore as your error message clearly told you. Your dump is text not binary dump format.